# Controlling Spotify app from another app, and playing offline tracks

Tags: ios, uri, spotify, offline

In iOS I can launch the spotify app from my app, and play tracks using the following scheme:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify:http://open.spotify.com/track/6ORL67wC1oHx1hq82e244g"]
];
```

Is there a way to do this for offline tracks i.e. tracks that are cached on my iphone. I don't want to have to have an internet connection if I've already cached the track.